# Region of convergence of $\sum_0^\infty a_k x^k$, when $\alpha= 0.a_oa_1a_2a_3...$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

if $\alpha= 0.a_oa_1a_2a_3...$ and $\alpha$ is irrational.

What is the region of convergence for:

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$

(region of convergence is defined as the max value of x with which the series convergences). Seems to me like this would converge as long as $|x|<1$, so $ROC=1$ but having trouble starting the proof.

Comment: $|x|<1,$ not $x<1.$

Comment: @zhw yes ;) Edited.

Comment: Radius of convergence is related to $\limsup a_k^{1/k}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we can use the fact that the coefficients are bounded? We have:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} x^{k} \textrm{ where } 0 \le a_{k} \le 9
$$
so
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} x^{k} 
\le 
9 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k} 
$$
The radius of convergence for the last series is 1 and so I think we can conclude that the radius for the original series is at least 1.

Comment: yes, this is correct. I am still having difficulty proving that it is exactly 1 and not more than 1.

Comment: @Dole the sequence $a_n$ doesn't converge to $0$, so the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ doesn't converge at $x = 1$. this means radius of convergence is at most $1$.